# mixpanel track form submission with validation

Tags: forms

I have a form which I want to use mixpanel to track some properties when I submit. How can I stop the form submit through mixpanel if the validation return false ?

Here's my code in general.

My simple form

```
<form id="form" action="..." method="post" role="form">
    // my elements here
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My script

```
<script>
    function(){
        mixpanel.track_forms("form", "MyEventName", getProperties());
        $("form").submit(SubmitForm);

        function getProperties(){
            // get properties here
        }

        function SubmitForm() {
            if (SomethingNotRight()) { return false; }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

My problem:

I expect that in my SubmitForm function, after validation by `SomethingNotRight` function, it will stop the submit. However, even when `SubmitForm` returns false, the form keep submitting to the server, which I found out is because of the `mixpanel.track_form`.

The reason I use `mixpanel.track_form` is to avoid the race condition between form submit and mixpanel submit as [debugging mixpanel track form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905553/debugging-mixpanel-track-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can definitely understand the issue here, and the reason is that track_forms is just designed for the default use case of a form submitting right away. If you have a process in between (in this case a validation), you should basically do your own implementation. The idea of track_forms is to identify the form being submitted, log the event, wait for a while so that the event can be saved, and then proceed. In that sense, you can do:

```
(function(){})(
    var theForm = $("#form"),
        readyToProceed = false;

    //listen for the submition
    theForm.submit(function(e){
        if(!readyToProceed){
            e.preventDefault();
            processSubmit();
        }
    });

    function processSubmit(){
        //validation process
        if (SomethingNotRight()) { return false; }

        //we are all good, lets proceed
        mixpanel.track("Form submitted");
        readyToProceed = true;
        window.setTimeout(function(){ theForm.submit() }, 300);
    }

);
```